# Finding possible destinations give list of values

Tags: javascript

I have the following **payload**

```
[ 
  {
    source: 'A',
    arrive: null,
    depart: 30
  },
  { 
    source: 'B',
    arrive: 45,
    depart: 40
  },
  {
    source: 'C',
    arrive: 25,
    depart: null 
  }

]
```

The **expected output** is the following

```
[ 
  {
    source: 'A',
    dest: 'B'
    arrive: 45,
    depart: 30
  },
  { 
    source: 'A',
    dest: 'C',
    arrive: 25,
    depart: 30
  },
  {
    source: 'B',
    dest: 'C',
    arrive: 25,
    depart: 40 
  }

]
```

I am attempting to use recursion to get the expected output and struggling with the logic. What would be the best way to attain the above expected output? Below is what I have right now and not sure if its the right way to go about it

I am using the permutations logic down here where, going to able label my objects as 1,2,3

> ```
> determineRoutes([{1}, {2}, {3}])
> {1} + determineRoutes([{2}, {3}]) ...
> ```

```
const determineRoutes = (routes) => {
    let result = [];

    if(routes.length === 1){
        result.push(routes[0]);
        return result;
    }

    for(let i = 0; i < routes.length; i++){
        let current = routes[i];
        let remaining = routes.slice(i + 1);
        let process = determineRoutes(remaining);

        for(let j = 0; j < process.length; j++){
            if(current.source !== process[i].source && current.depart !== null){
                let obj = {};
                obj['source'] = current.source;
                obj['dest'] = process[i].source;
                obj['depart'] = current.depart;
                obj['arrive'] = process[i].arrive;

                result.push(Object.assign({}, obj));
            }
        }
    }

    return result;
};
```

Comment: try to explain your logic, how are you getting from payload to expected output?

Comment: @CertainPerformance yes i forgot the quotes

Comment: @ChrisLi I am applying permutations logic, gonna edit it with explanation

Comment: Combinations without repititions

Answer (score 1):

Here's a basic implementation using [`Array.prototype.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce):

```js
const input = [{
  source: 'A',
  arrive: null,
  depart: 30
}, {
  source: 'B',
  arrive: 45,
  depart: 40
}, {
  source: 'C',
  arrive: 25,
  depart: null
}];

const output = input.reduce((a, v1, i, data) => {
  for (let j = i + 1; j < data.length; j++) {
    const v2 = data[j];
    a.push({source: v1.source, dest: v2.source, arrive: v2.arrive, depart: v1.depart});
  }
  
  return a;
}, []);

console.log(output);
```

This yields your expected output:

```
[
  {
    "source": "A",
    "dest": "B",
    "arrive": 45,
    "depart": 30
  },
  {
    "source": "A",
    "dest": "C",
    "arrive": 25,
    "depart": 30
  },
  {
    "source": "B",
    "dest": "C",
    "arrive": 25,
    "depart": 40
  }
]
```

Answer (score 1):

The list has three data payloads nested inside an array, the data schema is as follows:

```
source: [unique string id]
arrival: [time||false]
depart: [time||false]
```

I am going to use the exclusion principle and eliminate data outputs from sources that don't depart. So the code below loops through and finds out if the data departs if it does it sends it to the scheduler function and schedules it for all the payloads that allow arrivals, it than goes back to the main thread loop and finds the next departing payload. I really call recursive since the main loop doesn't call itself but I believe it may work.

```
var data = [ 
  {
  source: 'A',
  arrive: null,
  depart: 30
  },
  { 
  source: 'B',
  arrive: 45,
  depart: 40
  },
  {
  source: 'C',
  arrive: 25,
  depart: null 
  }
]
var schemaArray = [];
function scheduler(payloaded, schedule){
  // Global function that gets the output
  var store = {}
  // Check schedule for sources that allow arrivals
  for(var i = 0; i < schedule.length; i++) {
    // Ensure your data source doesn't match the payload
    if(schedule[i].source !== payloaded.source && schedule[i].arrive !== null) {
        // store a scheduled payload
        store.source = payloaded.source;
        store.dest = schedule[i].source;
        store.arrive = schedule[i].arrive;
        store.depart = payloaded.depart;
        // push to the schemaArry
        schemaArray.push(store);
      } 
    else { null; }
  }
  return true;
}
// Loop through the array payload finding sources that have no departures
  // To eliminate it from inclusion in the returned output
  // Since the expected output only includes sources that depart.
for(var z = 0; z < data.length; z++) {
   // Here I use a ternary operation but this
   // checking to see if the data payload departs
   data[z].depart === null ?
    null : scheduler(data[z], data);
}

console.log(schemaArray);
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
const nodes = [ 
  {
    source: 'A',
    arrive: null,
    depart: 30
  },
  { 
    source: 'B',
    arrive: 45,
    depart: 40
  },
  {
    source: 'C',
    arrive: 25,
    depart: null 
  }
];

const results = nodes.filter(node => node.depart) // Filter the nodes to just the ones that have a depart
  .reduce((results, node) => // Reduce the nodes to an array of results
    [
      ...results, // Spread the existing results into a new array
      ...nodes.filter(n => n.arrive && n.source !== node.source) // Filter the nodes to just the ones that have an arrive and are not the current node
        .map(
          n => ({ source: node.source, dest: n.source, arrive: n.arrive, depart: node.depart }) 
        ) // Combine the source node and destination node into a result object
    ],
    [] // The initial empty array to with no results
  );

console.log(results);
```

Comment: Happy? I am just used to my IDE formatting my functions and they are harder to format in that snippet editor.

Comment: It is only more efficient because it only looks forward, it will not work for most data sets.